# Ali Express Dropshipping uploading icon not showing in Bagisto Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm using bagisto version 0.1.6 and i have integrated the plugin for Ali Express Dropshipping. but there is a problem it is not showing the upload icon in ali express products. Please tell me what's the problem with that. I have already added the google extension and put the site site url, username and token there. But still not showing the upload icon in Ali Express Products.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly update your bagisto version and also do check when you have downloaded the aliexpress plugin as it was also updated recently due to some changes in AliExpress UI.